# Dealing with a Column of Lists in a Tidy Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

We are given data on sales records for Lego construction sets for 1000 customers as below:

```
[
  {
    "gender": "Female",
    "first_name": "Kimberly",
    "last_name": "Beckstead",
    "age": 24,
    "phone_number": "216-555-2549",
    "hobbies": ["Ultimate Disc", "Shopping"],
    "purchases": [
      {
        "SetID": 24701,
        "Number": "76062",
        "Theme": "DC Comics Super Heroes",
        "Subtheme": "Mighty Micros",
        "Year": 2016,
        "Name": "Robin vs. Bane",
        "Pieces": 77,
        "USPrice": 9.99,
        "ImageURL": "http://images.brickset.com/sets/images/76062-1.jpg",
        "Quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I covert the sales object into a tidy data frame:

```
(purchases = sales %>%
    tibble::tibble(item = .) %>%
    tidyr::unnest_wider(item) %>%
    select(gender, first_name, last_name, hobbies, phone_number, purchases) %>%
    tidyr::unnest_longer(purchases) %>%
    tidyr::unnest_wider(purchases))
```

And I try to calculate what are the five most popular hobbies of Lego purchasers:

```
purchases %>%
  select(hobbies) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    most_pop_hobbies = sum(hobbies),
    .groups = "drop_last") %>%
  select(hobbies, most_pop_hobbies) %>%
  slice_max(most_pop_hobbies, n=5) %>%
  distinct()
```

I get the error message:

> `Error in UseMethod("collapse") : no applicable method for 'collapse' applied to an object of class "character"`

I believe that this error arises due to the variable `hobbies` being a list, but I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You share JSON input, but your code seems to assume it has already been converted to a data frame/tibble. It does seem surprising that you are trying to drop groups in your summarize even though you have no `group_by`. Does `purchases` look right? If so, then it would be useful if you'd delete the JSON and the `purchases` creation code, and just give a reproducible sample of `purchases`. If not, then let's focus on that problem instead.

Comment: In the question we assume that the original data was stored in a JSON format but a colleague has managed to import it into R as a list of lists (of lists). We use ```sales = readRDS("data/lego_sales.rds")``` to load a copy of the object, called ```sales```.

Comment: ```purchases``` does look right, with `gender, first_name, last_name``` all being of type ```<chr>``` and ```hobbies`` being of type ```<list>```

Comment: Can you share the code of exactly how you bring the JSON into R?

Comment: @boshek No! We need less - not more. OP has successfully imported the JSON and created `purchases`. We need OP to delete the JSON, delete the `purchases` creation code, because it is all working. If OP then shares `dput(purchases[1:10, ])` to share a few example rows of purchases, we can then focus where the problem is - going from `purcases` to find the most popular hobbies.

Comment: The function dput(purchases[1:10, ]) returns this: 

structure(list(gender = c("Female", "Male",..., hobbies = list(c("Ultimate Disc", "Shopping"), c("Topiary", "Inline skating"), c("Topiary", "Inline skating"), c("Mahjong", "Sudoku", "Listening to music"),...

Comment: @GregorThomas I disagree because how the JSON is imported into R is relevant to approaches used to process the data. For example the data might unnecessarily be nested and could be flattened immediately upon import.

Comment: @GregorThomas in the question we're given a .rds file which we load into R using ```sales = readRDS("data/lego_sales.rds")``` I hope that clears things up. Where can we go from here?

Comment: We can go to you giving us an illustrative sample of the `purchases` data frame so we have something to work with. `dput(purchases[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows, or some other subset if it illustrates the problem better.

Comment: Hey @GregorThomas , I believe I provided the output of ```dput(purchases[1:10, ])``` in the comment above

Comment: You provided enough of it to show that you ran the command, but we need the whole unedited output to be able to copy/paste it into R and get your data. No "...". Please edit the whole thing into your question.

Comment: @codemachine98 can you add more rows to your input please? Also if you could explain how you get from the input JSON to `sales` that would be great thanks!!